# How to debug a stack overflow exception?

Tags: c++, debugging, stack-overflow

I am working on a game, and everything was fine, until I added some features. I worked for about one month on this features, and unfortunately I wasn't wise enough to test smaller parts of the code, so I have added many codes, and now I get this error.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77555098 (ntdll.dll) in SFML setup.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x006D2FA8).
```

my code is large, and it will be really hard, to check every single function. In the debugger call stack this specific function is repeated many many times.

```
void SceneNode::onCommand(const Command &command, sf::Time dt)
{
   if (command.category.at(getCategory()))
      command.action(*this, dt);

   for(const Ptr& child : mChild)
   {
      child->onCommand(command, dt);
   }
}
```

SceneNode is tree structure, and has some child. this function try to iterate through the tree, to see which nodes can take a specific command.

Comment: First step: Which one of the following possibilites applies? a) The child of a node X (or the child of the child of ... X) is X itself. b) Some buggy code inserted a large number of nested children, but the children should not exist. c) The data is ok, and the stack is indeed too small.

Comment: Prime suspects: `command.action(*this, dt);` calls this function, or `this` is an element of `mChild`. Look at the `this` pointer along the call stack in your debugger to see if you have a loop in the node tree.

Comment: Can't answer this question based on the information provided. Please provide a minimal working example that demonstrates the error. Creating a minimal working example usually helps you identify the issue.

Comment: Maybe you did not have a tree but a graph (ie you have cycle). One way to debug is to add some bool member to set true when you are inside oncommand method.

Comment: @deviantfan I will check for a and b, but couldn't understand C, what you mean by "stack is too small"?

Comment: @LokiAstari how I should provide a minimal working example?

Comment: @shayan: Like everybody else. Remove code until it works. Put back what you just removed (so it still breaks). Then Repeat the processes for all other parts of the code). Once you only have the code that breaks post it here.

Comment: @shayan If A and B do not apply, it's C. C means it's not your fault, and solutions are either to set appropriate compiler options or to remove the new features completely. ... (My first comment and this one too assume the data and `child->onCommand(command, dt);` are the problem. If `.action` somehow calls this function again, it's technically C, ie. data ok, but still your fault)

Comment: "stack is too small" ... well, stack has some limits, the computer has only so much memory. From the "ntdll" I would guess you are in Windows? I think modern Windows add stack dynamically as long as they manage to detect the app is running out of it, until whole dynamic memory is used (not sure, haven't seen Windows for a decade). You can probably help the OS by some advanced compiler/linker options to estimate the common stack usage, and give that estimate to OS. But anyway, you should put any large memory structures rather on heap. And "flatten" your structures. But this looks more like A/B.

Comment: @Ped7g `I think modern Windows add stack dynamically as long as they manage to detect the app is running out of it, until whole dynamic memory is used ` Never heard of that (but I too do not use much Windows)

Comment: @deviantfan I think it maps some invalid page under current stack, so at first thread access to it, it will trap to OS, which will enlarge the stack allocation and map additional mem pages under original ones, again ending with trap one. But I'm not going to verify this, who cares about windows today??

Comment: @Ped7g Far too many people :D

Comment: You are going to have to write debuggable code to have any shot at diagnosing the problem.  You need a static *int* to measure the recursion depth, set it to 0 in the caller.  The Command type needs a *visited* variable so you can detect a child pointing back to a parent.

Comment: @HansPassant I will definitely will look into those techniques, they are beyond my knowledge, thanks. can you give an exact name or some links, or some references?

Comment: Be also aware, that really deep tree structures written in modern C++ way with member variable like `class node { unique_ptr<node *> mChild; };` may overflow stack upon calling destructor of some high level node (going recursively to the bottom of tree). So once you know your data structures will be huge enough, you have to refactor a bit that initial simple implementation to not trigger deep recursion during node delete. But with small/medium sized structures go for the simple+working source first, optimize for performance only later, when you have something working and you can profile it.

Comment: @deviantfan I found the bug finally!! unfortunately it was where I didn't expect at all! it was in the at(getCategory()). there was a change, at return type of getCategory(), but at was the same as before, but code still was correct because an EVIL implicit conversation, and that made if to be true all the time! so there were too many calls to action.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to the question: "How to debug a stack overflow exception?".
1- Bug reproducible? if yes go ahead
2- Attach/open your process with windbg (or ollydbg or any other)
3- Trigger your exception
4- See the content of register (particularly (for 32 bit) `eip`, `ebp`)
5- dump `esp` in order to examine the stack frame
It should be like:

```
{ Local Var -> Saved EBP -> Saved EIP -> Params -> Address of Exception Handler }
```

You can find a really good and detailed explanation at this [link](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/25/writing-buffer-overflow-exploits-a-quick-and-basic-tutorial-part-3-seh/)